# How to target a specific key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a simple program and need help.

```
memory = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
for key, value in memory.items():
    print(key)
```

I need to target a specific key like this:         `x = '2'`, `memory = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}`, `for k, v in memory.items(x):`, `print(k)`. My idea is that the x should decide which key should be printed by it's value.

Comment: It currently prints both the `a` and `b` key, but you *only* want to print the `b` key and not the `a` key? Is your goal to print the key's values? Or only the key? How many times do you want the `b` key to print in the `for` loop?

Comment: I explained it poorly at the start, I need to target a specific key like this:         x = '2', memory = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, for k, v in memory.items(x):, print(k). My idea is that the x should decide which key should be printed by it's value.

Comment: You're still not explaining it very well, IMO. Do you know the difference between keys and values in a dictionary? Dictionaries are usually used to look-up the value associated with a _key_ — but it sounds like, _maybe_, you want to find the key(s) that have a certain value, which is the opposite.

Comment: Well, it' solved now anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking for, but do you want to print the value?

```
 memory = {'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
 for key, value in memory.items():
     print('key = {}'.format(key))
     print('value = {}'.format(value))
```

or only the `b` value?

```
print(memory['b'])
```

or do you want to print the key for which the value is `B`?

```
for key, val in memory.items():
     if val == 'B':
         print('key = {}'.format(key))
```

Comment: I explained it poorly at the start, I need to target a specific key like this:         x = '2', memory = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, for k, v in memory.items(x):, print(k). My idea is that the x should decide which key should be printed by it's value.

Comment: Lol, I just now realized that I should use a if statement like you said... Thanks.

Comment: @NemPlayer. No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keys()` method to get list keys and then iterate over them in the for loop

```
       memory = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'} 
       for key in memory.keys():     
            print(key)
            # if you need the corresponding value
            print(memory[key])
```

Comment: I explained it poorly at the start, I need to target a specific key like this:         x = '2', memory = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, for k, v in memory.items(x):, print(k). My idea is that the x should decide which key should be printed by it's value.